# How to permanently set refresh interval for top command?

Tags: 18.04, top

I'm just looking at the tutorials for `top` command and came to know that the refresh interval can be overridden by hitting lower case `s`  on the keyboard while the `top` command is displaying information.

The default value for refresh interval was `3` seconds. I was able to override the refresh interval to different value.

However, when I quit and come back and try the `top` command again, it is refreshing the processes information again for every `3` seconds and not with the interval that I've set earlier.

I was looking for a way to configure this interval permanently. I've looked at some articles where in they mentioned to use the `toprc` file in `/etc` directory for this configuration.

But it doesn't seem like I have any such file in `/etc` or my home directory.

How do I set the refresh interval for `top` command?

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personal configurations such as this may be saved to your `~/.toprc` file by hitting <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in the interactive `top` session.

From `man top` (or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/top.1.html)):

> ```
>  6b. PERSONAL Configuration File
>    This  file is written as `$HOME/.your-name-4-top' + `rc'.  Use the
>    `W' interactive command to create it or update it.
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Why not just launch top with a preset interval like this `top -d 5`. Which will make top start preconfigured to update every 5 seconds.

Comment: If I do that, I had to do `top -d 5` everytime instead of `top`.

Comment: Then save this as a one liner script named `/bin/pot` and you'll never have to save a personal config for each user, albeit at the modest price of having to type `pot` every time you want `top`

Comment: What about an alias `alias top="top -d 5"`?

Comment: `alias top="top -d 5"` works but only for the current shell, unless you make it permanent by `sudo echo "alias top="top -d 5"" >> ~/.bashrc`